# Evaluating Algebraic Complexity of a S-box

Tags: aes, s-boxes, algebraic-attack

While studying the design and the desirable properties of an AES S-box , I came to know that Algebraic Complexity is also an important property of an S-box which is usually considered while evaluating the properties of an S-box.

After reading several papers (such as [APA](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.8337&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), I get to know that Algebraic Complexity is basically the number of terms appearing in the "Algebraic Equation" representing that S-box.

After doing a bit of a research ([source](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~caw4567/docs/caw_thesis_p5.pdf)) I get to know there are three main methods for finding the polynomial equation to represent S-box which are:

1. Lagrangian interpolation
2. Polynomial linearization
3. Q-ary polynomial deduction

But honestly I am unable to understand any of the above methods to find the algebraic equation of the given S-box. So that ultimately I can evaluate it's Algebraic Complexity.

So, if someone can explain it in detail (or algorithm for the same), it would be really helpful for me to write the code for it. Or if there is some other way (or codes) to find Algebraic Complexity or Algebraic Equation of an AES S-box please share it.

**TL;DR:** Given an S-box ($n \times n$) , how can we evaluate its Algebraic Equation or Algebraic Complexity?

Comment: Both the paper and the slides you point to are reasonably well-defined [there may be some notational issues in the slides] but unless you understand the mathematics, it's not going to help, since you're essentially asking someone else to turn the mathematics into an algorithm [in whatever language] for you. The prerequisite to understanding both those sources is undertanding finite field arithmetic. Of course complexity can be defined at many different levels, in terms of circuit components, program code length, terms in algebraic expressions, etc. etc.

Comment: Have a look at the pre-print at http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04319 "Generating S-Box Multivariate Quadratic Equation Systems And Estimating Algebraic Attack Resistance Aided By SageMath".

Answer (score 3):

The interpolation of Sbox is based on Lagrange algorithm.
the following three steps are used to calculate the interpolation of S-box:

1. represent the S-box values as polynomial system, where P and C are polynomial representation of S-box input and output.
2. M (N x N ) is a matrix composed of P power polynomial. N is sbox size (256 for 8-bit sbox)
3. solve B form the following equation: **M.B=C**

> ```
> # the Equation is M.B=C.
> #     1  p0  p0^2  p0^3  p0^4  p0^5 .......  p0^d   
> #     1  p1  p1^2  p1^3  p1^4  p1^5 .......  p1^d
> #  M= 1  p2  p2^2  p2^3  p2^4  p2^5 .......  p2^d
> #     1  p3  p3^2  p3^3  p3^4  p3^5 .......  p3^d   
> #       .
> #       .
> #       .
> #     1  pn  pn^2  pn^3  pn^4  pn^5 .......  pn^d 
> #  size of M is dXn , d and n are equal for sbox, they are GF (2^8) (8-bit sbox)
> # Calculation steps. 
> #   1. convert Sbox table to polynomial of input and output, vectors (P is input  and C is output)
> #   2. calculate M table  
> #   3. B=M.solve_right(C)
> #
> ```

The following code is implementation of interpolation representation of Rijndael S-box

```
f=x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+1  # irreducible polynomial
L.<z>= GF(2^8,modulus=f)
R=PolynomialRing(L,'x')
N=256
M=matrix(L,N,N)
S=[0x63, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x7B, 0xF2, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0xC5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2B, 0xFE, 0xD7, 0xAB, 0x76, 
                             0xCA, 0x82, 0xC9, 0x7D, 0xFA, 0x59, 0x47, 0xF0, 0xAD, 0xD4, 0xA2, 0xAF, 0x9C, 0xA4, 0x72, 0xC0,
                             0xB7, 0xFD, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3F, 0xF7, 0xCC, 0x34, 0xA5, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x71, 0xD8, 0x31, 0x15,
                             0x04, 0xC7, 0x23, 0xC3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9A, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0x27, 0xB2, 0x75,
                             0x09, 0x83, 0x2C, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0x52, 0x3B, 0xD6, 0xB3, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x2F, 0x84,
                             0x53, 0xD1, 0x00, 0xED, 0x20, 0xFC, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xCB, 0xBE, 0x39, 0x4A, 0x4C, 0x58, 0xCF,
                             0xD0, 0xEF, 0xAA, 0xFB, 0x43, 0x4D, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x50, 0x3C, 0x9F, 0xA8,
                             0x51, 0xA3, 0x40, 0x8F, 0x92, 0x9D, 0x38, 0xF5, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0x21, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xD2,
                             0xCD, 0x0C, 0x13, 0xEC, 0x5F, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xC4, 0xA7, 0x7E, 0x3D, 0x64, 0x5D, 0x19, 0x73,
                             0x60, 0x81, 0x4F, 0xDC, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xEE, 0xB8, 0x14, 0xDE, 0x5E, 0x0B, 0xDB,
                             0xE0, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5C, 0xC2, 0xD3, 0xAC, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xE4, 0x79,
                             0xE7, 0xC8, 0x37, 0x6D, 0x8D, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x56, 0xF4, 0xEA, 0x65, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x08,
                             0xBA, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x1C, 0xA6, 0xB4, 0xC6, 0xE8, 0xDD, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x4B, 0xBD, 0x8B, 0x8A,
                             0x70, 0x3E, 0xB5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xF6, 0x0E, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xB9, 0x86, 0xC1, 0x1D, 0x9E,
                             0xE1, 0xF8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xD9, 0x8E, 0x94, 0x9B, 0x1E, 0x87, 0xE9, 0xCE, 0x55, 0x28, 0xDF,
                             0x8C, 0xA1, 0x89, 0x0D, 0xBF, 0xE6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2D, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x54, 0xBB, 0x16] # rajS-box 

C=vector(L,N)
P=vector(L,N)

# step 1
for i in range(0,N):

    P[i]= (i) + z^1*(i>>1) + z^2*(i>>2) + z^3*(i>>3) + z^4*(i>>4) + z^5*(i>>5) + z^6*(i>>6) + z^7*(i>>7)
    C[i]= S[(i)] + z^1*(S[i]>>1) + z^2*(S[i]>>2) + z^3*(S[i]>>3) + z^4*(S[i]>>4) + z^5*(S[i]>>5) + z^6*(S[i]>>6) + z^7*(S[i]>>7)


#print P
#print C
# step 2
for j in range(0,N):
    for i in range(0,N):
        M[j,i]= P[j]^i





#step 3
B=M.solve_right(C)



print B
```

Answer (score 0):

It is nice for me to have stumbled upon this old question. The S box consists of the composition of linear circulant operation $\text{L}$ composed with a nonlinear operation denoted $\text{Inv}()$ and adding the number 63 in hex in reverse order on an 8 bit $x$. Since $x$ can be considered an element of $\text{F}_{2^8}$, the algebraic equations of the $\text{Inv}()$ operation can be written along with operation by $\text{L}$ and addition of the constant. So focus on writing algebraic MQ equations in $x, \space y$ where y=Inv(x). The $\text{Inv}()$ is defined by $\text{Inv}(x)=x^{-1}$ in the field when $x\neq 0$ and $\text{Inv}(x)=0$ when $x=0$. The algebraic equations in $x, \space y$ are
$xy^2-y=0, \space yx^2-x=0$. These satisfy the $\text{Inv}()$ exactly.