# System equations for S-boxes

Tags: block-cipher

I`m on searching of any method of building system equations for S-boxes.
Firstly, I just cannot undestand exact meaning of "system equations", is it anf for each input (I know how to make it using Sage, maybe someone can help you make it using Magma)?
If not, please, maybe you have any articles or can a little bit describe algorithm.

Comment: Possible help https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/evaluating-algebraic-complexity-of-a-s-box/62767#62767

Comment: this https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/589.pdf explains how to generate Multivariate Quadratic Equation Systems

Comment: eprint.iacr.org/2015/589.pdf -- useful for S-boxes, which has description like AES, but if it has only table, not

Comment: It's a system, i.e., a set of simultaneous equations. See the excellent comments.